# Fancybox inside Ajax content

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, fancybox

I use ajax to present content on my website. When clicking in menu it opens stuff inside #content div. Here is my ajax code.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.menu li a').click(function(){
        var toLoad = $(this).attr('href')+' #content';
        $('#content').animate({"width": "0px"},'normal',loadContent);
        window.location.hash = $(this).attr('href').substr(0,$(this).attr('href').length-5);
        function loadContent() {
            $('#content').load(toLoad,'',showNewContent());
        }
        function showNewContent() {
            $('#content').animate({"width": "0px"},'fast');
            $('#content').animate({"width": "664px"},'fast');
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

I want to use Fancybox lightbox effect (http://fancybox.net) inside my ajax content. Below is code needed normally for Fancybox.

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("a#example4").fancybox({
                'opacity'       : true,
                'overlayShow'   : false,
                'transitionIn'  : 'elastic',
                'transitionOut' : 'elastic',
            });
        });
    </script>
```

How can I get this working? Ajax call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `load` callback handler should be a function pointer `showNewContent()` will right away call the function. Try this.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.menu li a').click(function(){
        var toLoad = $(this).attr('href')+' #content';
        $('#content').animate({"width": "0px"},'normal',loadContent);
        window.location.hash = $(this).attr('href').substr(0,$(this).attr('href').length-5);
        function loadContent() {
            $('#content').load(toLoad,'',showNewContent);
        }
        function showNewContent() {
            $("#example4").fancybox({
                'opacity'       : true,
                'overlayShow'   : false,
                'transitionIn'  : 'elastic',
                'transitionOut' : 'elastic',
            });
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be very close. Fancybox script seems to be working but it doesn't load image. It gives me always error message "The requested content cannot be loaded". This is the line what shoud give bigger image: `<a id="example4" href="big.png"><img src="small.png" /></a>`

Answer (score 0):

First this line is wrong

```
$('#content').load(toLoad,'',showNewContent());
```

It is saying call `showNewContent()` and assign whatever it returns to this event.

It should be

```
$('#content').load(toLoad,'',showNewContent);
```

Now it says to assign a reference to this function and run it when it is needed.

Now to answer your question, you need to call `$("a#example4").fancybox({...});` after the content is loaded, so that means you would put it in the function `showNewContent`.